# Export remote Postgres table to CSV file on local machine

Tags: postgresql, export, csv, copy

I have read-only access to a database on a remote server. So, I can execute:

```
COPY products TO '/tmp/products.csv' DELIMITER ',';
```

But on that server I don't have permissions to create/save a file, so I need to do this on my local machine.

When I connect to the remote database, how can I execute a command to save the file on my local machine instead of the remote server?

Or, how can I execute a Linux command to connect to the remote database, execute a query, and save the output as a file to my local machine?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Both the approaches already suggested appear to be unnecessarily complicated.

Just use `psql`'s built-in `\copy` command, which works just like server-side `COPY` but does a copy over the wire protocol to the client and uses client paths.

Because it's a `psql` backslash command you omit the trailing semicolon, eg:

```
\copy products TO '/tmp/products.csv' CSV DELIMITER ','
```

See [the `\copy` entry in the manual for the `psql` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY) and the [`COPY` command documenation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) for more detail.

Just like `COPY` you can use `\copy` with a `(SELECT ...)` query instead of a table name when copying data out (but not in).

---

A generally inferior alternative that can be useful in a few limited situations is to use:

```
psql -t -P format=unaligned -P fieldsep_zero=on -c 'SELECT * FROM tablename'
```

and use the `-o` flag or shell output redirection to write the output to a file. You should almost always use `\copy` in preference to this.

Comment: But this doesn't allow for transactions :(

Comment: Um, sure it does. Use a here-document to feed `psql` a script, starting with `BEGIN`, then doing your `\copy` commands, then a `COMMIT`. Or use `psql -f` to run a script rather than using a here-document.

Comment: Thanks for getting back... that's what I ended up doing and it worked =)

Comment: You can use `-A` instead of `-P format=unaligned` and also i think you need a `-P fieldsep=,`

Answer (score 4):

The Linux command is:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U username -o file.csv -c 'select id, name from clients;'
```

Comment: That won't produce CSV, it'll produce formatted text output. If you added `-t -P format=unaligned ` to that command you'd get something a little closer, like buggy pipe-delimited CSV, but pipes in the text wouldn't get escaped so it'd be invalid.

Comment: Oh, you'd also want `-P fieldsep=','` except that this would be even more likely to cause errors due to lack of escaping. `-P fieldsep_zero=on` would be OK if you didn't mind parsing null-byte-delimited text, as null bytes can't occur in `psql` output naturally.